# do I need memcache-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I am on rails 2.3.5 and ruby on 1.8.7. I have a single application using a local memcached (latest version from apt-get memcached) instance. It seems memcached is working as expected but going through the docs and other comments,

1 - It seems memcached-client is recommeneded for speeding things up. I can't tell for sure with my version of rrails/ruby if I really need it or not. Right now I use Rails.cache.read/write/fetch commands. I have installed this gem and I wonder what is interfacing with memcached without this gem and if it's good enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rails currently natively uses memcache-client (if available) when you type Rails.cache.
So you've got hat working just fine.

Here's a slideshare of memcache with rails, showing its usage:
http://www.slideshare.net/guestac752c/caching-memcached-and-rails

As to speed, I quite like some of the quick-and-dirty benchmarks on this tutorial just to make me feel better about cacheing:
http://townx.org/rails_and_memcached

It also has an interesting comparison between memcahe-client and Ruby-MemCache gems.
Note, however, that the above links are sadly aging (as is everything written about rails)... so take with a pinch of salt :)

Comment: So just to be clear if I install memcache-client rails will automatically use it, if it's not there then it uses what?